# Does adding more RAM affect the frame rate in games?

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon

I have a laptop that has an AMD A8-6410 APU with AMD Radeon R5 Graphics running Windows 8.1 (64 bit). It currently has 4GB RAM installed. When I play "Need for Speed: Most Wanted (2012)", I get a frame rate of about 15-20 fps. Will upgrading the RAM to 8 or even 12 GB help with the frame rate?

Comment: Its very unlikely additional memory will make any difference.  To put it simply your [hardware](http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/CYRI/Requirements/need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012/11368?p=r) isn't powerful enough for the program you want to run.  You already have the recommended amount of memory, and since its a 32-bit application, it can't use more then 4GB of system memory anyways.

Comment: i doubt it.  The game might launch a little faster, especially if you're running other things at the same time, but actual framerate is gonna be mostly based on your gfx card's power.

Comment: So is there anything I can do to improve my gaming performance?..and As I corrected in the question I have a windows 64 bit system.

Comment: Yea Ramhound was saying that 32-bit apps/OS can't deal with 4gb things; it's larger than the bit depth allows.  That's not really relevant though since we're talking about the system, not the game.  Having more ram on the system just means it can hold more of the game files in RAM at any given time.  Anyway, no.  You need a better GPU

Comment: @Bharat - Your performance bottleknecks are not with your memory though.  The game itself can only use 4GB ( 32-bit process ) and unless you are running out of memory already ( which isn't going to be the case with your situation ) adding more memory will have 0 effect on performance within the game.  Your system is not using all its current memory, so adding more memory, will do nothing.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing adding more ram will likely affect is the loading time between areas of the game. The more ram you have the more areas that can be kept "in memory" and will have faster access times.

FPS is very tightly linked to the performance of your video card above any other factor, using a laptop you do not have many options for improving that.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it will. I have the same setup and i just upgraded to 8gb of ram. The way AMD A4, A6, A8, A10 work is that the cpu and gpu are one and share system ram. This is called an apu. So even though it says 4gb  really your getting 3.5ish with .5gb going to the gpu portion of the apu. When I upgraded to 8gb 1gb went to the apu automatically, the rest went to the system. While this apu will benefit from 8gb greatly this wont turn it into a gaming laptop. I tested with bf3 and a few other games and the results were much better but still laughable(for bf3 that is). With 4 gb of ram I had 5-10fps in bf3 on low 720p, now im getting 15-24 on low 720p. Better but still under the 30fps console level. If i drop the resolution to 480p(LOL) i get 30fps. Bf3 though is a very heavy game on all systems and lighter games like cs:go, cod,  and mmorpgs play fine now even on high settings. I can now have a game and mutiple chrome tabs open with music playing and be getting a decent fps. Just make sure your laptop has 2 slots, mine didn't and I had to get the more expensive 8gb ram module instead of adding a 4gb one. Either way as long as you get 1600mhz ram your apu will overclock it automatically to 1866mhz Also a side note make sure your power settings are maxed out when gaming for the best use of your apu. Hope this helps.